# Emissions and omissions

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> Dust to dust, an undertaking,
>   unannounced, from under quaking,
>   understand our mother's shaking,
>   unlit hours unawaking.
>
> Embark my flight and take my place,
>   enjoy a clear breeze on my face,
>   and broadcast live to my fan base,
>   escape, I'm gone without a trace.
>
> Ill-conceived was Ian's sacking,
>   in his coat a gun he's packing,
>   in the night are sparklers cracking,
>   woods ignite in judgment's lacking.
>
> All aboard, have a glass and a snack,
>   the dam and turbines are seen out back,
>   and after all, it's off a duck's back,
>   as Adam gets another six-pack.

1. Find out the **one-word answer**.
2. Which paragraph do you **least associate** with the answer?

Hint:

> Each paragraph has an answer. Together the answers point to what *type* of thing we're looking for. And the four paragraphs together point to the final answer.

Hint #2:

> Each paragraph has four clues, one per line.

Hint #3:

> The final clue is related to letters and how each paragraph is written.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Partial Answer

The one word answer to the first part of the puzzle is

> Elements

```
Dust to dust, an undertaking,
unannounced, from under quaking,
understand our mother's shaking,
unlit hours unawaking.
```

> Earth. The lines describe a Earthen burial, earthquake, Mother Earth, and I think a Buddhist belief which hopefully refers to Earth in some way?

```
Embark my flight and take my place,
enjoy a clear breeze on my face,
and broadcast live to my fan base,
escape, I'm gone without a trace.
```

> Air.  The lines describe flying (taking to the air?) and feeling the breeze (catching air?).  Air can mean broadcast.  The last line could refer to airing something out.

```
Ill-conceived was Ian's sacking,
in his coat a gun he's packing,
in the night are sparklers cracking,
woods ignite in judgment's lacking.
```

> Fire.  Fire can mean to end employment, or discharge a gun.  Sparklers are fireworks.  Forest fires can be started by bad judgment.

```
All aboard, have a glass and a snack,
the dam and turbines are seen out back,
and after all, it's off a duck's back,
as Adam gets another six-pack.
```

> Water.  The first line refers to a glass of water.  Dams and turbines are used for storing water and generating energy.  There's an expression "water off a duck's back."  Bottled water can come in six-packs.

I don't know the answer to the second part.

Comment: Looking at this later, there may not have been enough clues to get the second part as written. I should maybe have just gone with the one that you found as the final answer... I'll accept this, but will post my original idea in a separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is:

> Natural Disasters <s>War</s>

The first paragraph relates to:

> An Earthquake <s>The feeling of the earth shaking as you're being bombed. (Like in the blitz)</s>

The second paragraph relates to:

> A Tornado/Hurricane <s>Becoming a fighter pilot, feeling the breeze on your face and having fans (civilians) wave you off to war as you disappear across the channel.</s>

The third paragraph relates to:

> Forest Fire? <s>A night time raid on an enemy position that went wrong and caused explosions and fires.</s>

The fourth paragraph relates to:

> A Flood (either from a broken dam or a tsunami) <s>Operation Chastise aka Dambuster where they successfully blew up a dam after dropping bouncing bombs which bounced on the water (like water off a duck's back) and they celebrated with a few beers afterwards.</s>

I least associate:

> The fourth paragraph as if it's from a broken dam, then it's kind of man-made rather than natural.  <s>The third paragraph as at first it sounds like bonfire night with fireworks.</s>

Comment: I don't know. This is all very loose, isn't it?

Comment: it's what it made me think of  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: There's a bit more wordplay included in the intended answer. I have added a hint.

Comment: @jafe have edited my answer

Answer (score 3):

I have accepted Ben J's answer, but wanted to post what I originally had in mind.

Each paragraph points to

> a classical element (earth, air, fire and water)

and each is written

> with three lines starting with a certain vowel (U, E, I, A).

What's been omitted is

> O, the remaining one of the five English vowels

which also happens to be

> an element, oxygen.

The paragraph you'd least associate with that is

> the first one (related to earth). Oxygen is a part of the water molecule, fire requires oxygen to burn, and air contains oxygen.

Comment: Hm. I had seen the pattern of the verses, but thought that the odd one out in each verse (D, A, W, T) was special. I also tried to take the letters of the verses' answers at the position of these "special" letters, but to no avail. I think this would have worked better if all lines of each stanza has the same letter at the beginning.

Comment: @MOehm Yeah I agree, that would have been much clearer.

Comment: I had the right thing from each paragraph (the names Ian and Adam helped), but didn't think to check what had been omitted.  Nice puzzle!